# Combining the Parameter Properties shorthand with Destructuring in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

### EDIT

I logged [an issue on TypeScript's Github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326) and they're accepting PRs for implementing it.

---

In TypeScript, when we want to automatically create properties in our class from the constructor definition, we can take advantage of the Parameter Properties shorthand, e.g:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public firstName : string, public lastName : number, public age : number) {

    }
}
```

And then, the transpiled Javascript will be:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

---

But if we want to receive an object in our constructor, it would be something like:

```
interface IPerson {
    firstName : string,
    lastName : string,
    age: number
}

class Person {
    constructor(person : IPerson) {
        this.firstName = person.firstName;
        this.lastName = person.lastName;
        this.age = person.age;
    }
}
```

Since TypeScript 1.5, we can take advantage of destructuring, e.g:

```
class Person {
    constructor({firstName, lastName, age} : {firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number}) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

---

**Question**: How to combine the Parameter Properties shorthand and Destructuring in TypeScript?

I've tried to define `public` before the object definition, e.g:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public {firstName, lastName, age} : {firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number}) {

    }
}
```

Tried to define it before each variable, e.g:

```
class Person {
    constructor({public firstName, public lastName, public age} : {firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number}) {

    }
}
```

But I had no success. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to `Object.assign`, this works:

```
class PersonData {
  firstName: string
  constructor(args : PersonData) {
    Object.assign(this, args)
  }
}

class Person extends PersonData{}
```

But note new instances will be populated by *anything* in args--you can't strip out just the keys you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't currently a way to do this short-hand, so the closest you can get is to declare the properties longhand and assign the variables from the destructuring assignment:

```
class Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;

    constructor({firstName, lastName, age} : {firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number}) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

If you are doing that... you'll probably just decide to accept an `IPerson` and assign its members without using destructuring in the constructor at all.

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy is to use the ability to assign to a variable of a different name. This cuts down on one repetition in the constructor.

```
class Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(args: { firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number, }) {
        ({
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            age: this.age,
        } = args);
    }
}
```

You can also move one of the definitions in the constructor to an interface.

```
interface PersonConstructorArgs {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
}
class Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(args: PersonConstructorArgs) {
        ({
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            age: this.age,
        } = args);
    }
}
```

This will be useful when you have a hierarchy.

```
interface PersonConstructorArgs {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
}
class Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(args: PersonConstructorArgs) {
        ({
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            age: this.age,
        } = args);
    }
}
interface EmployeeConstructorArgs extends PersonConstructorArgs {
    manager: Person;
}
class Employee extends Person {
    manager: Person;

    constructor(args: EmployeeConstructorArgs) {
        super(args);
        ({
            manager: this.manager,
        } = args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why is it necessary to wrap the destructuring assignment within parenthesis? I mean e.g. the outer `()` in `({ manager: this.manager } = args);`. I found that to be necessary when mapping over object properties (as *this.manager*), while usually they are not needed when mapping over local variables

Comment: There is a note in the [Object Destructuring section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring) of the TypeScript handbook that says "Notice that we had to surround this statement with parentheses. JavaScript normally parses a { as the start of block."

So the reason is that it would think it was a block instead of an object destructuring.